# Using ArcPy to adjust graduated color symbology

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology, runtimeerror, arcgis-10.8

I need to create a number of maps showing graudated colors based on different fields from layers across a few data frames. I have all layers symbology set to graduated colors but have encountered an error when trying to set the field and number of classes to use for the symbology. Here is the code I'm working with:

```py
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df):
        if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
            lyr.symbology.valueField = "MY_FIELD_NAME_HERE"
            lyr.symbology.numClasses = 4
```

When I run this in the Python window in ArcMap 10.8, I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 9, in 
> File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects_base.py", line 89, in _set
> return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
> RuntimeError

Comment: Your code works fine for me. This suggests something odd about a layer in your dataset, try putting in a print statement printing layer name before you attempt to change the symbology?

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd, good suggestion. When I add a statement to print layer name before changing symbology, it returns the first layer's name, then the error message mentioned in the question. I'm wondering if there's an issue with how Arc Desktop and Python are configured on my machine?